How to enable TLS on Spring TcpNioClientConnectionFactory + TcpInboundChannelAdapterSpec client connection to a TLS server?
I have an IntegrationFlow bean that uses TcpNioClientConnectionFactory, Tcp.nioClient, and TcpInboundChannelAdapterSpec to create a TCP Client connection to a TLS Server. I need to enable TLS on this connection to the server by using keys+certs. What is the correct way to implement this?
